# Easy way to correct Colour Constancy using Color by Correlation algorithm

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-enhancement

Recently, I've been implementing a variety of algorithms whilst attempting to learn Matlab.

One paper I've been reading is: [Color by Correlation](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=505472), which is cited by the thousands and used for comparison within many other color constancy experiments.

Unfortunately I can't find a single example online (unlike MaxRGB examples and other white-point estimations which are everywhere).

Can this be implemented in Matlab with minimal code? If so, can someone point me to a source or provide an example.

Comment: How about [this](http://scien.stanford.edu/pages/labsite/2009/psych221/projects/09/rangan/)?

Comment: That was the only one I found, but it seems over complicated as it uses no Matlab functions and requires ISET toolbox... I was hoping for a relatively simple one to begin with which could be done in Matlab alone. Thanks for posting.